# Plot Points from dictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, mkannotation

I'm getting latitude, longitude and many other fields from the server.

I put each row from the database in a separate dictionary within a array.

I'm trying to map out a point from the latitude and longitude, but when I try to access the latitude by key I get a compiler error `No visible @interface for NSDictionary...`.

Server Response

> [{"id":1,"user_id":0,"latitude":"42.2367","longitude":"-71.11332","status":"active","responded_at":null,"created_at":"2015-04-13T12:52:51.144Z","updated_at":"2015-04-13T12:52:51.161Z"},{"id":2,"user_id":0,"latitude":"42.23497","longitude":"-71.11238","status":"active","responded_at":null,"created_at":"2015-04-13T12:57:03.000Z","updated_at":"2015-04-13T12:57:03.002Z"},{"id":3,"user_id":0,"latitude":"42.24222","longitude":"-71.11536","status":"active","responded_at":null,"created_at":"2015-04-13T12:57:49.012Z","updated_at":"2015-04-13T12:57:49.014Z"},{"id":4,"user_id":0,"latitude":"42.24194","longitude":"-71.11556","status":"active","responded_at":null,"created_at":"2015-04-13T13:03:10.710Z","updated_at":"2015-04-13T13:03:10.713Z"},{"id":5,"user_id":0,"latitude":"42.23493","longitude":"-71.11244","status":"active","responded_at":null,"created_at":"2015-04-13T13:05:39.713Z","updated_at":"2015-04-13T13:05:39.716Z"},{"id":6,"user_id":0,"latitude":"42.23598","longitude":"-71.11467","status":"active","responded_at":null,"created_at":"2015-04-13T13:08:12.983Z","updated_at":"2015-04-13T13:08:12.986Z"},{"id":7,"user_id":0,"latitude":"42.23598","longitude":"-71.11467","status":"active","responded_at":null,"created_at":"2015-04-13T13:08:38.115Z","updated_at":"2015-04-13T13:08:38.118Z"},{"id":8,"user_id":0,"latitude":"42.23794","longitude":"-71.11471","status":"active","responded_at":null,"created_at":"2015-04-13T13:10:11.593Z","updated_at":"2015-04-13T13:11:19.467Z"}]

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    // The request is complete and data has been received
    // You can parse the stuff in your instance variable now

    NSError *error;
    NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                                       JSONObjectWithData:_responseData
                                       options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                                       error:&error];

    for (int i = 0; i < json.count; i++) {

        double latitude = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"latitude"];
        double longitude = [[[json objectForKey:@"longitude"]objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D latlng = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);

        MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
        [point setCoordinate:latlng];
        [worldView addAnnotation:point];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server response (like you say in the question) is an array of dictionaries.

So `json` should be declared as an `NSArray` not an `NSMutableDictionary`.

This is what causes the compiler error `No visible @interface for NSDictionary...` because `NSMutableDictionary` does not have a `objectAtIndex:` method.

In addition, the code to get the longitude is backwards (it treats `json` like a dictionary and then tries to access an array inside the resulting key value).

The corrected code would be:

```
NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                             JSONObjectWithData:_responseData
                             options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                             error:&error];

for (int i = 0; i < json.count; i++) {

    NSDictionary *pointDictionary = [json objectAtIndex:i];

    double latitude = [[pointDictionary objectForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];
    double longitude = [[pointDictionary objectForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D latlng = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);

    MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    [point setCoordinate:latlng];
    [worldView addAnnotation:point];
}
```